# Phonegap :difference between capture.captureImage and camera.getPicture

Tags: cordova, plugins, camera, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to create a phonegap app to capture image with its camera.
When i googled, i got two options 
ie using camera api and capture api.

what is the difference between `navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, options)` and `navigator.device.camera.getPicture(captureSuccess, captureError, options)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed one difference.

`navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, options)` on success save the image to default camera location where as 
`navigator.device.camera.getPicture(captureSuccess, captureError, options)` on success returns image as Base64 string

using navigator.device.capture we can also capture other media like audio(`navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1})`) and video (`navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1})`) which alse on success,saved to default location

Comment: Still no difference. You specify the output with the camera.destinationType not with the command itself.

Comment: I said I noticed " one" difference

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is still a difference, but in 2012 there were differences like you can see here:
[Get and Capture Differences](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/zeVrcIFch4Y)

*Camera.getPicture has a bunch of options that capture.captureImage does not. The other difference is capture follows a W3C spec while our camera spec is home grown.*

As i have just seen the `captureImage` command is from the [PhoneGap Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html)

The `getPicture` command is from the [Cordova Camera Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#navigatorcameragetpicture)

Answer (score 1):

[cordova-plugin-media-capture](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture#captureimageoptions)
capture.captureImage only supports one  option {limit : 1}

Provide option to capture audio and video as well.

Provide multiple capture

On other side [cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#cameracameraoptions--object) support number of custom options for capturing a image